# SwiftUI NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'd like to use the SwiftUI app lifecycle, but my app uses `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` to show a bar of tool options below the toolbar:

[image: toolbar]

Specifically, I'm doing this:

```swift
        let toolSettingsView = NSHostingView(rootView: ToolAccessoryView(model: model))
        let vc = NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController()
        vc.view = toolSettingsView
        vc.fullScreenMinHeight = accessoryHeight // Ensure tool settings are visible in full screen.
        toolSettingsView.frame.size = toolSettingsView.fittingSize
        window?.addTitlebarAccessoryViewController(vc)
```

**Is there a (practical) way I can mimic the control appearance (of the sliders, etc.) using pure SwiftUI?** When use a SwiftUI view I get this:

[image]

Code looks like this:

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    
    var model: DataModel
    var undoManager: UndoManager
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ToolAccessoryView(model: model)
            SculptingView(model: model, undoManager: undoManager)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is implemented as of macOS 13 by using a custom toolbar placement identifier as follows:

```
extension ToolbarItemPlacement {
    static let toolOptionsBar = ToolbarItemPlacement(id: "com.companyname.toolOptions")
}
```

Then specifying the placement in the `.toolbar`:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .toolOptionsBar) {
    ToolAccessoryView()
}
```

Which in my case looks like this:

[image: toolbar accessory view]

The colors on the sliders are a bit odd, which is likely their bug.

See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbarplacement/init(id:) which has some example code.